# Three doubts about off-policy n-step sarsa algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm reading the [public draft (pdf)](http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/bookdraft2016sep.pdf) of the 2nd edition of Sutton&Barto's RL Book.

There are a few things I don't understand about the Off-policy n-step Sarsa method described in the book. You can find the pseudo-code at page 159 (177) of the pdf I linked above.

Here's a picture of the pseudo-code for your convenience:

[image]

Here are the 3 things I don't understand:

1. $\rho$ considers the actions $A_{\tau+1},\ldots,A_{\tau+n-1}$. Shouldn't it also consider $A_{\tau+n}$?
2. In the third to last line, $\rho$ multiplies both $G$ and $Q(S_\tau,A_\tau)$. Shouldn't it multiply just $G$?
3. The second to last line says that $\pi$, if being learned, must be $\epsilon$-greedy wrt $Q$ (with $\epsilon>0$). I don't understand the reason of this restriction. Can't $\pi$ be greedy just like in Q Learning? The exploration is already taken care of by $\mu$.

Comment: Regarding point 2, I am having the same doubt, I actually asked the question before I found yours: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/reinforcement-learning-n-step-off-policy-sarsa-sutton-barto-2nd-ed-page-14

Comment: I even messaged Rich Sutton, hopefully we get an answer.

Comment: Were you able to clarify the question (since you asked yourself the same question two years ago :)?

Comment: With respect to question 2, both formulas would be correct as $\mathbf{E}[\rho]=1$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Aτ+n is omitted since it is the state at horizon for the n-step update and estimated value for its action-value will be used so weighting by its importance ratio is skipped.

2) I was wondering the same - it even makes my action-values to grow to infinity(with rewards -1.0 for all steps and 1.0 for goal reached). My implementation for n-Step Q(σ) estimation works fine with σ=1 matching the n-Step Tree Backup as expected but for σ=0 it reproduces the same problem with non-stop growing state-action-values as in the simple Off-Policy n-Step Sarsa.

3) If it is deterministic greedy then all its action probabilities for a given state will be 0 instead of the greedy action(for which will be 1.0) and thus the importance ratio product will be non-zero only when the actions chosen by the behavior policy will match the greedy policy - I don't think this will help exploration.